# Update: How to find event listeners on a DOM node in prototype?

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, listener, observer-pattern

I'm looking for an updated answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node).

It seems that Event.observers is no longer used (perhaps to avoid memory leaks) in Prototype 1.6+, so how do I track down now what event listeners are attached to an element?

I know Firebug has a "break on next" button, but there are several mouse listeners on the body element that execute before I can get to the behavior that I want on another particular element, so is there some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've update the answer [you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node) with more comprehensive `Prototype` coverage accounting for changes in versions `1.6.0` to `1.6.1`.

It got very messy in between there, but 1.6.1 is somewhat clean:

```
var handler = function() { alert('clicked!') };
$(element).observe('click', handler);

// inspect
var clickEvents = element.getStorage().get('prototype_event_registry').get('click');
clickEvents.each(function(wrapper){
    alert(wrapper.handler) // alerts "function() { alert('clicked!') }"
})
```

Comment: Thx for updating the other answer, too! I'm sure it'll help others who found it like I did through google.

Answer (score 7):

Things are now routed through Element storage : )

`Element.getStorage(yourElement).get('prototype_event_registry')` will give you an instance of Prototype's `Hash`, so you can do anything that you would do with hash.

```
// to see which event types are being observed
Element.getStorage(yourElement).get('prototype_event_registry').keys();

// to get array of handlers for particular event type
Element.getStorage(yourElement).get('prototype_event_registry').get('click');

// to get array of all handlers
Element.getStorage(yourElement).get('prototype_event_registry').values();

// etc.
```

Note that **these are undocumented internal details** which might be changed in the future, so I wouldn't rely on them except for, perhaps, debugging purposes.

Comment: +1 Thx, kangax. Although you were first, crescentfish gave a more complete answer with the 1.6.0.X version that I needed.