# Prototype - form collections of prototype listeners and dom listeners

Tags: javascript, prototype

How do you form a collection of all the listeners and functions for a given Element using prototype?

Also, is there a simple way to do this with normal Dom listeners on a given Element?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "collection" exactly?

Comment: a prototype hash or an array of listeners..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question should help, at least on the Protoype end:

[**How to find event listeners on a DOM node in prototype?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422696/update-how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-prototype)