# Prototype : Check if element is observed

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, observer-pattern

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update: How to find event listeners on a DOM node in prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422696/update-how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-prototype)

I would like to know if it's possible to check if an element is already observed using prototype.

Thanks

Comment: Wondering how a duplicate question voted up as well as someone's favorite.